# Problem curl: (35) error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version

Tags: linux, ssl, curl, kindle

i have problem to run script on kindle reader. i did jailbrake on it and it shows me system version

**Linux kindle 2.6.31-rt11-lab126 #5 Sat Jan 12 20:39:09 PST 2013 armv7l unknown**

the problem is with running the script to download the png image

```
curl https://kindle-pindle.herokuapp.com/ -o status.png
```

an error is returned

```
curl: (35) error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version
```

I read that it's probably about a bad version of curl but I can't do anything to install a new version because there is no apt-get or sudo in systm so I don't know how to do it
are there maybe other ways to deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

The target site requires at least TLS 1.2. Given the age of what you are running (according to the kernel version) this is likely not supported by the TLS stack on your device.

There is probably no way to download the file directly from the device though. You should be able to download the file on a different device and transfer it to the device though or maybe redistribute it through your own web server which has TLS 1.0 enabled.